# Firehose record format conversion partitions

Tags: file-conversion, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I tried to to use the new firehose feature "record format conversion" to save my events as parquet files for athena or hive aggregations. You have to select the table from your glue catalog, but firehose ignores the defined partions, and instead saves the files in the structure YYYY/MM/DD/HH/. The data also is missing the defined partition columns. This would be ok, if it has used it for partitioning.

Is there a API configuration, or something else, to force to use the table partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

I have exact the same issue, even with same partitioning

So you have to use AWS lambda to achieve what you want

1. one to move files generated by Firehose to bucket that is used by Athena.
2. another one to trigger refresh Athena table, as it will not see new folders
   (I don't put all triggers, but this should be just a call 'MSCK REPAIR TABLE your_table_name;')

For the first one I choose NodeJs, as this is really simple and really fast.
~ 3 seconds to move 120MB file with minimum AWS allowed 128MB RAM memory allocation(files generated by Firehose will be approximate 64MB max)

Node js project structure
package.json

```
{ 
  "name": "your.project", 
  "version": "1.0.0", 
  "description": "Copy generated partitioned files by Firehose to valid partitioned files for Athena", 
  "main": "index.js", 
  "dependencies": { 
    "async": "^2.6.1" 
   } 
}
```

And index.js

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const async = require('async');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const dstBucket = 'PUT_YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE';
var util = require('util');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    const split = srcKey.split('/');
    const dstKey = `event_year=${split[0]}/event_month=${split[1]}/event_day=${split[2]}/event_hour=${split[3]}/${split[4]}`;
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 10}));
    async.waterfall([
            function copy(next) {
                s3.copyObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    CopySource: `${srcBucket}/${srcKey}`,
                    Key: dstKey
                }, next);
            },
            function deleteOriginal(copyResult, next) {
                s3.deleteObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                }, next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Failed: ${srcBucket}/${srcKey} => ${dstBucket}/${dstKey} to move FireHose partitioned object to Athena partitioned object. Error: ${err}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`Success: ${srcBucket}/${srcKey} => ${dstBucket}/${dstKey} moved FireHose partitioned object to Athena partitioned object`);
            }
            callback(null, 'move success');
        }
    );
};
```

Just update some data to be valid for your case.
And one more issue that I got, is when build a project with

```
npm install
```

and zip it, it was something not correct in AWS unzip, so I have to update path to my index.js.

And this works.

You can also find this line

```
console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 10}));
```

It can be removed, but greatly helps to understand details of processing object